# Setting an auto id when Add an User in the same method of Update in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am adding the Add method in my CRUD Api.

I have to use the same form and the same method of update.
When I click on update the url is `detail/:id`, instead when I click on add the link is `detail/-1`.

In my method I have to control if the id equals `-1` id set a new Id doing a sum between `users.lenght + 1` else I pass to the form the id, and the other parameters to update.

```
  getUser(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.userService.getUser(id)
      .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    if (id === -1) {
      id = this.users.length + 1;
      this.userService.getUser(id)
        .subscribe(user => this.user = user);
    }
  }
```

I can't assign the new `id` to the old Id because it's a constant.
What do I have to do?

This is my form in html:

```
  <div *ngIf="user">
      <h2>{{user.firstName}} Details</h2>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="id">Id</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input id="id" name="id" type="text" placeholder="{{user.id}}"  class="form-control input-md" required="" readonly>
        </div>
      </div>

      /*rest of datas*/
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to change the active route you have to fire a navigation.

If you just need the id in the component you can use `let` instead of `const` or assign it to another variable.

Answer (score 1):

just declare the variable with `let` keyword. I'm not sure this is what you are asking though.

```ts
let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `const` you can't re-assing a variable, you have to use `let`

```
let id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
```

Also when you use `const` it's good practice to use uppercase